# Animate Windows desktop background using a timer in VB

Tags: vb.net, animation, timer, ffmpeg, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on code that should animate the desktop background using a timer and I achieved that using the code below, but I'n not planing to change it randomly to random wallpapers, so here is my problem, i'm using ([ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)) command-line to extract all the frames from a `GIF` image, then I'm running a timer with a low interval(100), to loop through all the frames and change the background using the `User32.dll` API, but the problem is that the animation is not very smooth as if you open it in the browser, and the program will be very slow during the animation, so I don't know if there is another way to change the background without the lag, here is what i have done so far :

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Auto Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal Z As String, ByVal W As Integer) As Integer
    Dim FrameX As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        'If the frame is not exist then loop from the begenning with the frame 0.
        If Not File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\Frames\animation" & FrameX & ".png") Then
            FrameX = 0
        End If
        Try
            SystemParametersInfo(20, 0, Application.StartupPath & "\Frames\animation" & FrameX & ".png", 1 Or 2)
        Catch ex As Exception : End Try

        FrameX += 1
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What do you mean by **smooth**, do you mean it's not fast? 
Also, I didn't understand why you put Timer1.Stop() at the beginning in Timer1_Tick and Timer1.Start() at the end.
Try removing Timer1.Stop(). You can also try to make the interval lower.

Comment: @Youssef13 ,  Yes, it very "laggy", not just slow, it may freeze for a second and continue with skipping 2-3 frames.

Comment: I suggest you didn't make the **Catch** part empty. Maybe there's an exception happening that makes some frames are skipped.

Comment: @Youssef13 , No errors, but i worked a little bit more on it and i got it and i'm happy with the result that i got, see it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5gugls3ly20y7ei/Clip-6.mp4?dl=0).

Comment: I suggest you add the solution as an answer in case someone meets the same problem or gets interested in this.

Comment: @Youssef13 , thanks for the suggest, i did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the issue is from the the memory or the `CPU` because the function `SystemParametersInfo` using the file `User32.dll` file so there is a lot of processing in the background and the timer is running very fast for that function, and `Windows` did delete this functionality after `Windows XP` for the same reason, the `RAM` is messing everything up, so i used this code to release the `RAM` from the usage of my program when ever i update the background, and it really make a different, it's not perfect but it needs powerful PCs :

**First, declaring this function :**

```
Private Declare Function SetProcessWorkingSetSize Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal dwMinimumWorkingSetSize As Int32, ByVal dwMaximumWorkingSetSize As Int32) As Int32
```

**Second, the usage :**

```
Sub ReleaseRAM()
    Try
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        If Environment.OSVersion.Platform = PlatformID.Win32NT Then
            SetProcessWorkingSetSize(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

---

**Also,** you should work on the interval of the timer and the number of the frames, if you have so many frames to animate, the interval should be high, so you have to find the right balance.

Running the program as administrator and giving it high priority also helps.

---

**Finally, Hope someone will find this useful or interesting :)**